# FrameTicks in BarChart

Tags: bugs, version-8, ticks, webmathematica

I am finding it a strange issue.
I want to make a  BarChart as

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 4}, Frame -> True, 
FrameTicks -> {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3, 4}, None}}]
```

And i want to control FrameTicks according to my will.
The strange part is, if I keep one of the axis as None then I get no error as shown below.

But if I mark all four sides of Frame using Frame ticks, it does not give me required result.
Can't figure out the problem.

[image]

Comment: Code same as shown in question.As you can see, in FrameTicks marked 3 sides of Frame, and left the fourth side as "None". If I put values for fourth side also, it does not give me out put. For example if on place of "None", I put {1,2,3,4}, I get figure with problem it gives following messages A tick style in the value of the Ticks option is not a directive.
A tick specification in the value of FrameTicks should be a number or list.

Comment: `BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 4}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3,
      4}}}]` works for me

Comment: Not for me. I don't know why

Comment: What version and os are you working on? Have copied my code, maybe there is a mistake in yours?

Comment: Its Mathematica 8.0 and Windows7. The thing is FrameTicks worked well for Plot but strangely not for BarChart

Comment: I can confirm this bug in version 8. So I'm tagging this as a bug that's specific to that version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in *Mathematica* version 8, and it can be fixed by specifying the `FrameTicks` outside of `BarChart` using a `Show` wrapper:

```
Show[BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 4}], Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3,4}}}]
```

[image: barchart]