# Place a small gap between axes and plot?

Tags: plotting

See for example this picture produced with R: [image]

You can see there is a small white space between the x-axis and the y-axis, so that the axes do not cross. How can I do this with Mathematica, for a `ListPlot` or a `Histogram`?

Comment: (+1) A very good example of what *should* be achievable with MMa in the easy!

Comment: This takes an unnatural amount of work (which it shouldn't). Maybe these related posts help: [FrameTicks in BarChart](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73970/245), [Labeling a bar chart, changing how rotated labels are centered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2652/245).

Comment: @Jens Especially, because one of the most useful functions for achieving this is broken since literally ever: [AbsoluteOptions](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hQup2.png)

Comment: @halirutan Even more handy function for such kind of tasks is [`FullGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullGraphics.html) but it does not work either.

Answer (score 34):

This can be done more-or-less easily with a combination of options for `AxesOrigin`, `PlotRange`, and `PlotRangePadding` and the [`CustomTicks` package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5599/) (for easy outward-facing ticks).

```
Needs["CustomTicks`"];

GapAxes[plot_Graphics, ticks : {{x__}, {y__}}, scalefactor_: Automatic] := With[
   {prange = ticks[[All, 1 ;; 2]],
    s = Flatten@{scalefactor /. Automatic -> 0.02 {1, 1/(AspectRatio /. Options[plot])}}},
   Show[plot,
    Ticks -> {LinTicks[x], LinTicks[y]},
    PlotRange -> (prange + Subtract @@@ prange {{First@s, 0}, {Last@s, 0}}),
    PlotRangePadding -> (Subtract @@@ prange {{First@s, 0}, {Last@s, 0}}),
    AxesOrigin -> (prange[[All, 1]] + Subtract @@@ prange {First@s, Last@s})
    ]
   ];
```

1. *`plot`* can be any plot or chart.
2. *`ticks`* gives the arguments of the `LinTicks` functions which specify the axes ticks. *`x`* and *`y`* must each contain a range specification (which also doubles as the `PlotRange` specifiation) as the first two items, but they may also include as additional items any of the other arguments that may be passed to `LinTicks` (`TickDirection -> Out`, perhaps).
3. The optional argument *`scalefactor`* specifies how far to separate the axes from the plot as a fraction of the total image dimensions. If *`scalefactor`* is not specified, the axes are separated by 2% of the total width.

---

**Examples**

```
data = RandomVariate[HalfNormalDistribution[1/150], 500];

GapAxes[
 Histogram[data, {100}], 
 {{0, 700, TickDirection -> Out}, {0, 200, TickDirection -> Out}}
 ]
```

[image: chart]

```
GapAxes[
 Plot[Tan[x], {x, -3, 3}], 
 {{-3, 3, TickDirection -> Out}, {-6, 6, TickDirection -> Out}}
 ]
```

[image: plot]

---

**Notes:**

1. It remains to be seen how robust this `GapAxes` function will prove to be, but the basic method should be pretty universal.
2. To see the whole plot when the axes are short, additional `ImagePadding` may be needed.

   ```
   GapAxes[
    Histogram[data, {100}, ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 50}, {Automatic, Automatic}}], 
    {{0, 600, TickDirection -> Out}, {0, 200, TickDirection -> Out}}
    ]
   ```

[image: chart2]

Answer (score 10):

This is tedious.. manually drawing the axes.

```
 GraphicsRow[{Histogram[data],
      Show[{Histogram[data  , PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.2], 
            Axes -> False,
            PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {0, 100}}], 
      Graphics[{Line[{Scaled[{.2, .15}], Scaled[{.8, .15}]}],
                Line[Scaled /@ {{#, .15}, {#, .1}}] & /@ Range[.2, .8, .1],
            Text[#, Scaled[{.6 (# + 3)/6 + .2, .04}], {0, 0}] & /@ 
                  Range[-3, 3, 1],
             Text[Rotate[ #, Pi/2], 
              Scaled[{.04, (#/100) .6 + .2 }], {0, 0}] & /@ 
               Range[0, 100, 25],
            Line[Scaled /@ {{.06, #}, {.1, #}}] & /@ Range[.2, .8, .1],
            Line[Scaled /@ {{.1, .2}, {.1, .8}}]}]}]}]
```

[image]

a bit of caution, I'm not certain the axes are precisely aligned.

Answer (score 5):

Not a real answer. But you can try to put your plot in `Inset[]`, then add another `Inset[]` for x-axis and yet another `Inset[]` for y-axis
and then stitch all scales together…
Something like this (nothing is stitched)

```
Graphics[{Transparent, Rectangle[], 
  Inset[ListPlot[{1, 2, 3, 4, 0}, Axes -> False, Joined -> True, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 0, Filling -> Bottom], {0, 0}, {0.1, -0.1}, 
   1], Inset[
   ListPlot[{}, AxesStyle -> Red, Axes -> {False, True}], {0, 
    0.05}, {0, 0}, 1],
  Inset[ListPlot[{}, AxesStyle -> Blue, Axes -> {True, False}], {0.05,
     0}, {0, 0}, 1]}]
```

[image]

This [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83636/how-to-align-coordinate-systems-of-inset-and-enclosing-graphics) is potentially useful for aligning three `Inset`s

Comment: try working with regular `Plot` for the axes then you can specify the `PlotRange`

Comment: @george2079 I can specify `PlotRange` for `ListPlot` as well… like you said it's just so tedious! I actually prefer your solution, it's straightforward and quite flexible. I thought about it but got scared to draw ticks myself...

Comment: yes you can. Actually the other issue I had in v9 `ListPlot` does not like an empty list.  You can give it an out of range point though to get an empty plot.

Comment: why do you need an empty plot?

Comment: that's what your `ListPlot[{}, ..` does. Just an axis with no data.  In v9 this throws an error "ListPlot called with 0 arguments" .  This tricks it into working : ListPlot[{""}, ... ]

Comment: I thought you meant completely empty plot with no axes...

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[ticksF, axesF, labelF]
ticksF[tSide_: Left, tr_: 1, tl_: (.01), s_: {Thickness[.001]}][{minmax__}, nd_:{6, 6}] :=
 Module[{tf = tSide /. {Automatic | Left -> Identity, Right -> ({-1, 1} # &), 
   Bottom -> ((Reverse@#) &)}, 
 d = {#, Complement[Join @@ #2, #]} & @@ FindDivisions[{minmax}, nd, Method -> {}], 
 trns = tSide /. {Left -> {-tr, 0}, Right -> {tr, 0}, Bottom -> {0, -tr} }, tcks}, 
 tcks = Join[Table[{i, i, tl, s}, {i, d[[1]]}], Table[{i, "", tl/2, s}, {i, d[[2]]}]]; 
 Translate[{s, Line@Thread[tf @
  {0, Through @ {Min, Max} @ #[[All, 1]]}], {Line[{tf @ {-#3, #}, tf @ {0, #}}],
  Text[#2,  tf[{1.2  tSide /. {(Left | Bottom) -> (-1) , (Top | Right) -> 1}, 1} {#3, #}],
   If[tSide === Bottom, {Center, tSide /. {Bottom -> Top, Top -> Bottom}}, 
    {tSide /. {Left -> Right, Right -> Left}, Center}]]} & @@@ #} &@tcks, trns]]

axesF[ tr_: {1, 1}, tl_: (0.01), ar_: 1/GoldenRatio][
   {rng1 : {_, __}, nd1_: {6, 6}}, {rng2 : {_, __}, nd2_: {6, 6}}] := 
 Module[{sc = ar (Subtract @@ rng1[[{2, 1}]])/ (Subtract @@ rng2[[{2, 1}]])}, 
  {ticksF[Bottom, tr[[1]], tl][rng1, nd1], ticksF[Left, tr [[2]] sc, tl  sc][rng2, nd2]}]

labelF = Labeled[#, {Rotate[#2, 90 Degree], #3}, {Left, Bottom}] &;
```

### Histogram

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomVariate[HalfNormalDistribution[1/150], 500];
hst = Histogram[data, Axes -> False, 
   ImagePadding -> {Scaled /@ {.04, .05}, Scaled /@ {.04, .025}}, 
   ImageSize -> 600, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
   Epilog -> (axesF[{5, 5}, 5][{{0, 700}}, {{0, 120}}]), 
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}];
labelF[hst, Style["labely", 20, "Panel"], Style["labelx", 20, "Panel"]]
```

[image]

### ListPlot

```
lp = ListPlot[data, Axes -> False, 
   ImagePadding -> {Scaled /@ {.04, .05}, Scaled /@ {.04, .025}}, 
   ImageSize -> 600, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
   Epilog -> (axesF[{20, 20}, 20][{{0, Length@data}}, {{0, 1.1 Max[data]}}]), 
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}];
labelF[lp, Style["labely", 20, "Panel"], Style["labelx", 20, "Panel"]]
```

[image]

### BarChart

```
bc = BarChart[d2 = HistogramList[data][[2]], Axes -> False, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   ImagePadding -> {Scaled /@ {.025, .025}, Scaled /@ {.05, .025}}, 
   ImageSize -> 600, AspectRatio -> ar, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
   Epilog -> (axesF[{5, 0}, 5][{{1, 1 + Length@d2}, {Length@d2, 1}}, {{0, 120}}]), 
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}];
labelF[bc, Style["labely", 20, "Panel"], Style["labelx", 20, "Panel"]]
```

[image]

### Plot

```
plot = Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, 
  ImagePadding -> {Scaled /@ {.05, .05}, Scaled /@ {.065, .05}}, 
  ImageSize -> 600, PlotRange -> {{-2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {-1, 1}}, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  Epilog -> (axesF[{1.1, 1.7}, .1][{{-2 Pi, 2 Pi, Pi/2}, {8, 2}}, {{-1, 1}}]), 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}]
labelF[plot, Style["labely", 20, "Panel"], Style["labelx", 20, "Panel"]]
```

[image]

**Note:** With some additional effort, some of the manual settings can be automated using `Scaled` and/or extracting plot range.