# How to avoid frames or axes from intersecting?

Tags: plotting, ticks

I want to have a plot, such that it is displayed like so;

[image]

so that the axes or the frames don't intercept.

I was able to achieve this only by covering with graphics, with epilog, like so:

```
SeedRandom[123]
data = Thread@{Range[8] + 1, RandomReal[{0, 0.8}, 8]};
ListPlot[data, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-0.1, 0.8}}, 
  Frame -> {{True, None}, {True, None}}, 
  Epilog -> {White, Rectangle[{-5, -6}, {1.98, 0.0 - 0.002}]}, 
  FrameTicks -> {Table[i, {i, 2, 10}], Table[i, {i, 0.0, 0.8, 0.1}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can do it with built-in options (i.e, `AxesOrigin`). I think that you will have to make the plot without an axes and then draw it in yourself or (as you have done) hide the offending corner.

Comment: In older versions of *Mathematica*, `ListPlot[{{2., 0.1}, {3., 0.8}, {5., 0.3}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]` produced output like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b3IcS.png). Not anymore…

Comment: There are some solutions [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86064/place-a-small-gap-between-axes-and-plot)